# PHP + Javascript: Need to use javascript in header location

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

So I have:

```
<?php

   header( 'Location: http://my-link' );
?>
```

and I need to track the page, but the tutorial I found teaches you how to do that in a link, and as you can see, I don't have a link, I use a page redirect.

The tracking code is

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   function recordOutboundLink(link, category, action) { 
     try { var myTracker=_gat._getTrackerByName(); 
     _gaq.push(['myTracker._trackEvent', category , action ]); 
     setTimeout('document.location = "' + link.href + '"', 100) 
    }catch(err){} 
   } 
</script>
```

It works with a link:

```
<a href="http://www.your-affiliate-link.com" onClick="recordOutboundLink(this, 'Affiliate Links', 'your-affiliate-link.com');return false;">
```

Is there a way to implement it on the php header part, instead of integrating in a link?

For example:

```
header( 'Location: http://my-link; onClick="recordOutboundLink(this, 'Affiliate Links', 'your-affiliate-link.com');return false;' );
```

EDIT

Here's what I'm trying to achieve: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/analytics/tXX--cOnkDs

EDIT 2

Here is the solution, I hope it may be useful for someone else:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-57067301-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>



<script type="text/javascript"> function recordOutboundLink(link, category, action) { try { var myTracker=_gat._getTrackerByName(); _gaq.push(['myTracker._trackEvent', category , action ]); setTimeout('document.location = "' + link.href + '"', 100) }catch(err){} } </script>

<script type="text/javascript">

recordOutboundLink(this, 'Affiliate Links', 'http://hotmart.net.br/show.html?a=F2357823M');
setTimeout(function(){window.location='http://hotmart.net.br/show.html?a=F2357823M';}, 500); // working with a 500ms timeout to make sure the tracking is done correctly

</script>
```

Comment: what does recordOutboundLink do?

Comment: Registers the user click.

Comment: How does the client get to the PHP page with the `header` redirect?  Can you record the outbound navigation from there?

Comment: It looks like you should be setting it as a paremter of the form using `_linkByPost()`. [Have a look at the documentation here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiDomainDirectory#_gat.GA_Tracker_._linkByPost)

Comment: That is not a PHP solution you asked for. As I remember, **_gaq.push** will create an image with src to google analitics, I am sure you can send similar request with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's not an "easy" solution, I would suggest tracking the navigation from the server via [Google's Analytics API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/hello-analytics-api).  That's going to be the cleanest and most holistic approach.

Comment: Someone just gave me the solution, but soon afterwards he deleted his comment.

Comment: Do you have to do a server side redirect?  Or can you instead echo a page that does that redirect w/ JavaScript?